# How to get in Go a std::string from an exported function of a DLL?

Tags: c++, go, dll, 64-bit

I want to load a custom DLL (C++ one) and call a function that it exports ?
Here is my Go code:

```
func main() {
    dllForGo := syscall.MustLoadDLL("dllForGo.dll")
    defer dllForGo.Release()
    getHello:= dllForGo.MustFindProc("getHello")
    r1, _, err := getHello.Call(0) // also tried with .Call() and still got the same error
}
```

Here the C++ code of my DLL:

```
 std::string __stdcall getHello(void) {
     int a = 1;
     double b = 10;
     return ("Hello-World !!"+std::to_string(a) + std::to_string(b));
}
```

I tried to force the use of __stdcall (and link a .def file for this, as I thought that maybe  __declspec(dllexport) could be a problem ).

However, using DUMPBIN, I can see that getHello uses __cdecl calling convention. Is it a problem?

And here is the error I get when I run my Go:

```
Exception 0xc0000005 0x1 0x10 0x7fef0591327
PC=0x7fef0591327

syscall.Syscall(0x7fef05910d0, 0x1, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
    D:/Go/src/runtime/syscall_windows.go:172 +0xf9
syscall.(*Proc).Call(0xc00004e420, 0xc000058090, 0x1, 0x1, 0x565520, 0x21, 0x2e06a0, 0x0)
    D:/Go/src/syscall/dll_windows.go:146 +0x140
main.main()
    D:/GoLand_Projects/dllLoad/main.go:58 +0x335
rax     0x22fdb8
rbx     0x9
rcx     0x30
rdi     0x9
rsi     0x0
rbp     0x22fdd9
rsp     0x22fd60
r8      0x30303030302e3031
r9      0x7fef1220000
r10     0x22fd90
r11     0x771a1f
r12     0xa
r13     0x9
r14     0x0
r15     0x0
rip     0x7fef0591327
rflags  0x10202
cs      0x33
fs      0x53
gs      0x2b
```

**EDIT**

The getHello function is actually well executed. I modified it to write to a file:

```
 std::string __stdcall  getHello(void) {
     std::ofstream outfile("D:\\test123.txt");
     outfile << "getHello working!" << std::endl;
     outfile.close();
     int a = 1;
     double b = 10;
    return ("Hello-World !!"+std::to_string(a) + std::to_string(b));
}
```

...and the file is written to. So the problem is at after the exported function returns.
 Which makes me think I need to change something in the Go part to "welcome" the returned std::string.

**EDIT2**

If I change the return type of the exported function to *void* then, the Call return without exception. Could it be an additional hint that it's indeed related to the calling convention ?

Comment: Please, provide a working example.

Comment: Go does not handle str::string directly, you should pass the string between DLL space and Go program space using C way: buffer and buffer size. The string owner is the Go program, the DLL just copy the return value into the buffer created by the caller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer I got from a gopher:

> working with objects is tricky. string is an object, it probably has a
>   vtable somewhere, it also has an internal structure (although I forget
>   what it is, my guess would be it's similar to a COM bstring or a go
>   slice, maybe check the relevant c++ sources). Calling methods would
>   involve finding the address of the dispatch table entires and calling
>   those as functions. I suggest you start with a C char * and work your
>   way to that.

So I tried by taking a char ** as argument , I could modify it in the DLL function and display the modification in Go. I also tried returning a basic type (int) and it worked also.

Comment: `std::string`, while having an interesting internal structure due to small-string-optimisation on most implementations (copy-on-write was often found pre-C++11), should not have anything to do with vtables or such.

Comment: Yes, I agree on that, it wasn't my words. But the important part here is that it's not the same internal structure (between std:string and char arrays), which is what causes the problem.